# How to manage campaign of AWS Pinpoint using code of php AWS-Sdk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

We are working on push notification for Android and iOS using AWS Pinpoint webservice. We have created and launched campaign in AWS pinpoint console.
But We want to manage segment, campaign etc from other webserver so that we need not to login AWS console repeatedly (client's requirement).

For such requirement, I am using AWS php sdk to achieve goal. I have written just simple code

```
require_once 'aws-sdk/aws-autoloader.php';
use Aws\AwsClient;

$objClient = new Aws\AwsClient([
            'version'     => 'XXX',
            'region'      => 'XXX',
            'credentials' => [
                'key'    => 'XXX',
                'secret' => 'XXX'
            ]
        ]);
```

But it gives following error:

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'The service "" is not provided by the AWS SDK for PHP.' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/researchworks/vipin/pinpoint-demo/aws-sdk/Aws/functions.php:347 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/researchworks/vipin/pinpoint-demo/aws-sdk/Aws/AwsClient.php(129): Aws\manifest('') #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/researchworks/vipin/pinpoint-demo/index.php(13): Aws\AwsClient->__construct(Array) #2 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/researchworks/vipin/pinpoint-demo/aws-sdk/Aws/functions.php on line 347
```

I have used https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.Pinpoint.PinpointClient.html for pinpoint documantation.
Please provide solution of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how to instantiate a raw AWS Client, though I'm guessing if you provide `"Pinpoint"` as the `service` argument it might work.

From the [documentation provided](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.Pinpoint.PinpointClient.html) a Pinpoint client can be instantiated and called

```
require_once 'aws/aws-autoloader.php';

use Aws\Pinpoint\PinpointClient;

$client = PinpointClient::factory(array(
    'profile'=>'CREDENTIAL_PROFILE', //Or you can provide the raw credentials as you did in your sample
    'region'=>'us-east-1', 
    'version'=>'2016-12-01'
));
$result = $client->getApps();

print $result;
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion. Yes you are right, I corrected my mistake and include 'use Aws\Pinpoint;' so that I am able to instantiate the object using  $objPinpoint = new Aws\Pinpoint\PinpointClient([
    'version'     => 'XXX',
    'region'      => 'XXX',
    'credentials' => [
     'key'    => 'XXX',
     'secret' => 'XXX'
    ]
   ]);

Comment: But Now I am facing new problem. After instantiate object I am trying to call function provided in documentation but it gives following error: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Aws\Pinpoint\Exception\PinpointException' with message 'Error executing "GetApps" on "https://pinpoint.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/apps"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 35: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to pinpoint.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443 (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)' exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException' with message

Comment: 'cURL error 35: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to pinpoint.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443 (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/researchworks/vipin/aws-sdk-new/GuzzleHttp/Handler/CurlFactory.php:186 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/researchworks/vipin/aws-sdk-new/GuzzleHttp/Handler/CurlFactory.php(150): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::createRejection(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Array) #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/researchworks/vipin/aws-sdk-new/GuzzleHttp/Handler/CurlFactory.php(103):

Comment: I was trying most of function but it gives same type of error. So Please suggest something to overcome from this problem

Comment: Sounds like some SSL version issue, a quick google found: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=163438 Not sure where these things are set, but I just verified that the ZIP archive PHP AWS SDK worked for me on PHP 5.6.30

Comment: Yes, You are right. It is SSL version issue. I have tried same code in different server with higher ssl version then it is working fine.

Comment: @Cheruvian it looks like you guys have experience with aws pinpoint. Could you help me by taking a look at the question I am linking below? I greately appreciate your answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55226785/how-do-i-store-aws-pinpoint-messages-to-rds